# Bootstrap tab how to get value base from tab input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

so, basically this is my page for you to test = http://www.greenthumbgifts.com.au/buy/Mothers-Day/Eucalyptus-and-Lemon-Candle-with-Native-Gum/252?&templatebody=test2

I want you to go to "Personalise your gift" section at the right corner of the page, test the YES button and there is collapsible content with bootstrap tabs in it, it only gets the value from first input text(cutting board), but NOT the 2nd tab(flower box), and 3rd tab(ribbon). you will see the value of input after putting text then press enter OR click okay. pls check. I want to take the value also the 2nd and 3rd tab by tab name(maybe?). pls help. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user presses OK or hits enter, you use

```
var rText = $("input.rInputText").val();
```

to get the value of the textbox. The problem is that you have 3 different textboxes that have the same class of "rInputText" so when you use

```
$("input.rInputText").val();
```

it just picks up the first element that matches the selector, which is the textbox shown in the first tab in this case.

I suggest changing it to be

```
var rText = $(".tab-pane.active input").val();
```

With the ".tab-pane.active" in the selector, it looks for the elements that have the class "tab-pane" AND "active", so only the active input picked up.